# GET http://localhost/chat_functions.php?action=getUser 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, visual-studio-code

I am having some problems with my ajax calls. I need to access the chat_functions.php file which is located inside my project named Meet.

[The location of chat_functions.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbBlh.png)

My url in my ajax call leads correctly to the location of the file but when I check in on Chrome Developer tools, the url is different hence the error 404 NOT FOUND occurred. I will really appreciate any help in solving this issue. Thanks.

[Error in Chrome Developer Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPR67.png)

[Ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhLKh.png)

Comment: Does you ajax call have `MEET` in the url which isn't anywhere else?

Comment: @NigelRen I'm sorry but what do you mean by "have **MEET** in the url which isn't anywhere else"?

Comment: The value of `url:` is not `http://localhost/chat_functions.php?action=getUser` (the last image in your question).

Comment: @NigelRen yes. That's the wrong path so I edited the url to `url: http://localhost/Meet/chat_functions.php?action=getUser` in the ajax call and saved the file. However after reloading the webpage, the url in Chrome Developer Tool did not change.